# Can not understand behaviour by passing arguments to Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, html

Consider following HTML Snippet with Javascript in it. Paste this code [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic) to see that stuff running in the Tryit Editor from W3Schools.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a href="javascript: submitQuickAddForm('00001030')">Number with quotes</a><br>
<a href="javascript: submitQuickAddForm(00001030)">Number without quotes</a> <br>
<a href="javascript: submitQuickAddForm(hello)">Text with quotes</a> <br>
<a href="javascript: submitQuickAddForm('hello')">Text without quotes</a>
<script>
function submitQuickAddForm(itemNumber) {
alert(itemNumber);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The first link puts out 00001030.
The second: **536** Which I cant understand at all ?!
The third link does nothing (maybe no type for the parameter specified)
and the last link works well again (output: hello)

So whats with the second and third link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is string, the second one is interpreted as octal number because of leading 0.

**EDIT:** Explanation from @RobG to question: *"but why can´t it alert just 00001030 or at least 1030? Why 536?"*

Because `Number.prototype.toString` assumes a radix of 10

**Update:**
The 3rd link does nothing because `hello` is not defined. Most probably you got error in console: `ReferenceError: hello is not defined`

Comment: Yea, the second one is a number.. but why can´t it alert just 00001030 or at least 1030? Why 536?

Comment: Ocatal is a number encoded in base 8. 1030 in base 8 is 536 in base 10.

Comment: @GedankenNebel, try this: http://www.translatorscafe.com/cafe/units-converter/numbers/calculator/octal-to-decimal/ and put the octal number in the first box.

Comment: @GedankenNebel—Because [`Number.prototype.toString`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1) assumes a radix of 10.